# Getting size of directories and exclude some folders

Tags: shell, command-line, disk-usage

I have an directory structure like this:

1. application1
2. application1_edit
3. application2
4. application2_edit

Is there any way to get the total size for every folder (including sub-directories) and exclude all folders with `_edit` in name?

I have tried `du -s` on the root folder, but it lists all sub-directories.

Comment: What if `ls | grep -v "_edit" | xargs du -s`in the root folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
$ du -s application[12]
```

#### Example

```
$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 28 01:51 application1
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 28 01:51 application1_edit
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 28 01:51 application2
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Nov 28 01:51 application2_edit
```

Disk usage:

```
$ du -s application[12]
4   application1
4   application2
```